# Hide center tab bar button when pushed view sets HidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I'm following the example on how to create a tab bar with a center button like Path,Instagram, etc from here: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

The problem I have is that when a view is pushed onto the stack that sets HidesBottomBarWhenPushed to hide the tab bar, the center button is still displayed.

In the comments, several other people have had this problem, but there's no working solution. (I've tried all the suggested solutions in the comments)

I came up with a hacky solution-- store a reference to the center button in an unrelated singleton class, and then have the pushed view hide the button when it is loaded, and unhide it when it dissapears-- but this just feels wrong, and it looks funny because you can see the button dissapear before the push view animation starts.

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: Im looking for a solution to the same, i tried [self.tabBar addSubView:button]; but it doesn't work

Comment: hope this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225696/how-to-hide-custom-tab-bar-button-when-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-is-true?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. 
I edited the BaseViewController.m (my UITabBarController subclass) by overriding the following viewDidLayoutSubviews method (button is my center button) as followed.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
}
```

Now your button follows the tabbar.

Comment: Remember to include `button.layer.zPosition = 1;` as well, in order to prevent button being covered by the tabbar

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this same but with UIImageView and add it to tabBar:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:               (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex != AUCenterTabBarButtonIntex) {
        self.centerImageView.highlighted = NO;
    } else {
        self.centerImageView.highlighted = YES;
        self.selectedIndex = AUCenterTabBarButtonIntex;
    }

}


- (void)addCenterImageViewWithImage:(UIImage *)image highlitedImage:(UIImage *)highlitedImage
{
    UIImageView *centerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2)];
    centerImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    centerImageView.image = image;
    centerImageView.highlightedImage = highlitedImage;

    CGFloat heightDifference = centerImageView.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        centerImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.tabBar.center.x, centerImageView.center.y);
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = (self.tabBar.frame.size.height/2) - (heightDifference/2);
        centerImageView.center = center;
    }

    [self.tabBar addSubview:centerImageView];

    self.centerImageView = centerImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before push UIViewController，add your custom button to UITabBar

After pop UIViewController, restore custom button to self.view

Subclass UITabViewController

```
NSArray *array=  self.viewControllers;
for(UIViewController *controller in array){
if([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
    UINavigationController *navigationController=(UINavigationController*)controller;
    navigationController.delegate=self;
   }
}
```

Implement delegate method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
if (viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) {
    CGRect rect= [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.tabBar];
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tabBar addSubview:button];
    button.frame=rect;
 }
}
-(void)navigationController:(nonnull UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
if(!viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed){
    CGRect rect= [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.view];
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    button.frame=rect;
}
}
```