# Custom Tab Bar button Not hiiding on push

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have 5 tabs and Center Button is custom, so i created a UITabBarController class to customize the center button. What is happening is when I do **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed** tab bar becomes hidden except the center custom button is still visible & not even disabled And when I tab

```
class TabBar: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet weak var centerButton:UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nImage = UIImage(named: "infobutton")
        let bImage = UIImageView(image: nImage!)
        bImage.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)


        let cButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        cButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
        cButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)
        cButton.setBackgroundImage(nImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cButton.setBackgroundImage(nImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

        cButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.centerButton = cButton

        var heightDifference:CGFloat = bImage.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height
        if (heightDifference < 0) {
            cButton.center = self.tabBar.center;
        } else {
            var center:CGPoint = self.tabBar.center;
            center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
            cButton.center = center
          }
        self.view.addSubview(cButton)

    }

    func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the button in interface builder a subview of the tab bar, or of the containing view?

Comment: subview of the tab bar

Comment: But I see button created programmatically and added to tabBarController.view not just tabBar. Possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225696/how-to-hide-custom-tab-bar-button-when-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-is-true